# How to make two joins between two tables in MySQL such that they are interlinked to each other?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two tables in a company database named `employee` and `branch` with a single foreign key each. The `employee` table looks like this:

```
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| emp_id     | int         | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| first_name | varchar(30) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| last_name  | varchar(30) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| birth_date | date        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| sex        | varchar(1)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| salary     | int         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| super_id   | int         | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| branch_id  | int         | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

And the branch table looks like this:

```
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field          | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| branch_id      | int         | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| branch_name    | varchar(30) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| mgr_id         | int         | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| mgr_start_date | date        | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

In the employee table, the `branch_id` foreign key references the `branch_id` of the `branch` table. In the branch table, the `manager_id` foreign key references the `employee_id` of the `employee` table.

I would form two joins between these two tables in *circular fashion*(saying informally) such that `employee.branch_id` forms a join with `branch.branch_id`, and such that `branch.manager_id` forms a join with `employee.employee_id`.

So what I want the query with these two joins to return is:

```
employee.first_name AS employee_name, employee.branch_id, branch.branch_name, branch.manager_id, employee.employee_id AS manager_name
```

I couldn't think of a possible solution to this issue as the LEFT table in each of the joins is different and I don't know how to define multiple LEFT tables for each join in a single SQL query.

DBMS: MySQL v8.0.26

P.S: My question is different from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18058312/two-joins-between-two-tables) as in the aforementioned question, the LEFT table for both of the joins is the same and in my case, it is not.

Comment: It's not clear what your assumptions or exact question are, please ask 1 clear precise complete question along with an example of it. Justify per authoritative documentation, people have misconceptions they could find themselves. Please in code questions give a [mre]. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. PS Put everything relevant to your question in the post itself & relate it to your post, don't expect us to read another post & guess what is relevant or how. [ask] [Help]

Comment: [FKs ("relationships") are not needed to query. (And tables represent relation(ship)s/associations.)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23842061/3404097) Constraints (including FKs & PKs) need not hold, be declared or be known in order to record or query. Joins are binary, the left table is the result of any previous joins in a series without parentheses. Except for output column order, inner & cross joins have no direction, t join u on c is u join t on c. You just need to mention a table/alias before dotting it.

Comment: [Re self-join & querying generally.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27682724/3404097)

Comment: I think the best way to show your table is by executing `SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name;` and post the result into your question. It'll show more than just column names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### How to proceed towards the solution

Two joins can be formed between two columns by using Table aliases. As the question specifies, that one join is to be formed between the `employee` and the `branch` table, and another join needs to be formed between the `branch` and the `employee` table. The little bit tricky part of these types of joins is the relation specified after the `ON` keyword that joins the two tables.

As @philipxy writes in a comment to this question:

> Constraints (including FKs & PKs) need not hold, be declared or be known in order to record or query. Joins are binary, the left table is the result of any previous joins in a series without parentheses. Except for output column order, inner & cross joins have no direction, t join u on c is u join t on c.

So according to the comment, we would form a join between `employee` and `branch` and another join between `employee` and an alias of branch table called `branch2`. The common confusion here is that most people(including me earlier) think that there is a "direction" of joins, the thing that philipxy covers in his aforementioned comment.

### The solution to the problem

You can write a SQL query which queries the `first_name`, `last_name` and `branch_id` from the `employee` table and the `branch_name` from the `branch` table and forms a join between the two tables on the basis of `branch_id`. You have to query the `mgr_id` from the alias of the branch table called `branch2`; you have to query the `first_name` and the `last_name` of the branch managers from the employee table. You can easily join the employee and the branch table on the basis of `emp_id` such that the `mgr_id`=`emp_id`.

You can finally write the SQL query for the problem like this:

```
SELECT employee.first_name, employee.last_name, employee.branch_id,
branch.branch_name,
branch2.mgr_id, employee.first_name AS manager_first_name, employee.last_name AS manager_last_name
FROM employee
JOIN branch ON employee.branch_id=branch.branch_id
JOIN branch branch2 ON branch2.mgr_id=employee.emp_id;
```

### Extra information

The above mentioned query would return this:

```
+------------+-----------+-----------+-------------+--------+--------------------+-------------------+
| first_name | last_name | branch_id | branch_name | mgr_id | manager_first_name | manager_last_name |
+------------+-----------+-----------+-------------+--------+--------------------+-------------------+
| David      | Wallace   |         1 | Corporate   |    100 | David              | Wallace           |
| Michael    | Scott     |         2 | Scranton    |    102 | Michael            | Scott             |
| Josh       | Porter    |         3 | Stamford    |    106 | Josh               | Porter            |
+------------+-----------+-----------+-------------+--------+--------------------+-------------------+
```

These results might look *useless* as we have formed an `INNER JOIN` between the tables so it just returns us the name of the employees who are "managers" of a specific branch. If you form a `LEFT JOIN` between the tables instead of an `INNER JOIN` you would get results like this:

```
+------------+-----------+-----------+-------------+--------+--------------------+-------------------+
| first_name | last_name | branch_id | branch_name | mgr_id | manager_first_name | manager_last_name |
+------------+-----------+-----------+-------------+--------+--------------------+-------------------+
| David      | Wallace   |         1 | Corporate   |    100 | David              | Wallace           |
| Jan        | Levinson  |         1 | Corporate   |   NULL | Jan                | Levinson          |
| Michael    | Scott     |         2 | Scranton    |    102 | Michael            | Scott             |
| Angela     | Martin    |         2 | Scranton    |   NULL | Angela             | Martin            |
| Kelly      | Kapoor    |         2 | Scranton    |   NULL | Kelly              | Kapoor            |
| Stanley    | Hudson    |         2 | Scranton    |   NULL | Stanley            | Hudson            |
| Josh       | Porter    |         3 | Stamford    |    106 | Josh               | Porter            |
| Andy       | Bernard   |         3 | Stamford    |   NULL | Andy               | Bernard           |
| Jim        | Halpert   |         3 | Stamford    |   NULL | Jim                | Halpert           |
+------------+-----------+-----------+-------------+--------+--------------------+-------------------+
```

These results were not as expected as the employees who are not managers of any branch just have a `mgr_id` with `NULL` value whereas the branch that they word in actually has a manager. With the `mgr_id` being NULL, the `manager_first_name` and `manager_last_name` have unexpected results too.

The above occurs because we cannot have the same manager for two employees because `mgr_id` can not be the same accross rows as it is the `emp_id` which is the PRIMARY KEY of the `employee` table.

### Credits

- @philpxy 's comments on this question